# Invalid center for newValue: {} - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I've made `ViewModel` LocCusCountVM.cs containing Location object as:-

```
public class LocCusCountVM
{
    public Location locations { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}

public partial class Location
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Lat { get; set; }
    public string Long { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CustLoc { get; set; }
}
```

Now I've a GetMarkerData in my HomeController as:-

```
public JsonResult GetMarkerData(int locationID)
{
    using (DbEntities dc = new DbEntities())
    {
        Location l = null;
        l = dc.Locations.Where(a => a.LocationID.Equals(locationID)).FirstOrDefault();

        var c = (from lo in db.Locations
            join lt in db.LocationTbls on lo.CustLoc equals lt.Id
            join ct in db.CustomerTbls on lo.CustLoc equals ct.Location
            where ct.Location == (from lo in db.Locations where lo.LocationID==locationID select lo.CustLoc).FirstOrDefault()
            select ct.Location).Count();

        LocCusCountVM LocCus = new LocCusCountVM();
        LocCus.locations = l;
        LocCus.count = c;
        LocCus.locations.LocationID = locationID;

        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = LocCus,
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
}
```

Then my Index.cshtml and CustForm.js are:-

```js
.controller('mapsController', function($scope, $http)   
{  
    //this is default coordinates for the map when it loads for first time  
    $scope.map =   
    {  
        center:   
        {  
            latitude: 28.6315,
            longitude: 77.2167
        },  
        zoom: 16  
    }  
    $scope.markers = [];  
    $scope.locations = [];  
    //to get all the locations from the server  
    $http.get('/home/GetAllLocation').then(function(data)  
    {  
        $scope.locations = data.data;  
    }, function()  
    {  
        alert('Error');  
    });  
    //service that gets makers info from server  
    $scope.ShowLocation = function(locationID)  
    {  
        $http.get('/home/GetMarkerData',  
        {  
            params:  
            {  
                locationID: locationID  
            }  
        }).then(function(data)  
        {  
            $scope.markers = [];  
            $scope.markers.push  
            ({  
                id: data.data.LocationID,  
                coords:  
                {  
                    latitude: data.data.Lat,  
                    longitude: data.data.Long  
                },  
                title: data.data.title, //title of the makers  
                address: data.data.Address, //Address of the makers  
                image: data.data.ImagePath //image --optional  
            });  
            //set map focus to center  
            $scope.map.center.latitude = data.data.Lat;  
            $scope.map.center.longitude = data.data.Long;  
        }, function()  
        {  
            alert('Error'); //shows error if connection lost or error occurs  
        });  
    }  
    //Show or Hide marker on map using options passes here  
    $scope.windowOptions =  
    {  
        show: true  
    };  
}) 
//mapsController Ends Here
```

```html
<!--Div for mapsController Upload Started-->
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div ng-controller="mapsController">
        <!--It displays the markers links-->
        <div class="locations">
            <ul>
                <li class="text-success" ng-repeat="l in locations" ng-click="ShowLocation(l.LocationID)"><a href="#">{{l.Title}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="maps">
            <!-- Add directive code (gmap directive) for show map and markers-->
            <ui-gmap-google-map style="box-shadow:2px 2px 2px 2px lightgrey" center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
                <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="marker.events" idkey="marker.id">
                    <ui-gmap-window options="windowOptions" show="windowOptions.show">
                        <div style="max-width:200px">
                            <div class="header"><strong>{{marker.title}}</strong></div>
                            <div id="mapcontent">
                                <p>
                                    <img ng-src="{{marker.image}}" style="width:200px; height:100px" />
                                    <div>{{marker.address}}</div>
                                    <b>No of Customers:</b>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ui-gmap-window>
                </ui-gmap-marker>
            </ui-gmap-google-map>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Div for mapsController Upload Ended-->
```

But each time I execute this I get an error:- `Invalid center for newValue: {}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your attribute names to camelCase.
(e.g. data.data.LocationID -> data.data.locationID)

CustForm.js

```
.controller('mapsController', function($scope, $http)   
{  
    //this is default coordinates for the map when it loads for first time  
    $scope.map =   
    {  
        center:   
        {  
            latitude: 28.6315,
            longitude: 77.2167
        },  
        zoom: 16  
    }  
    $scope.markers = [];  
    $scope.locations = [];  
    //to get all the locations from the server  
    $http.get('/home/GetAllLocation').then(function(data)  
    {  
        $scope.locations = data.data;  
    }, function()  
    {  
        alert('Error');  
    });  
    //service that gets makers info from server  
    $scope.ShowLocation = function(locationID)  
    {  
        $http.get('/home/GetMarkerData',  
        {  
            params:  
            {  
                locationID: locationID  
            }  
        }).then(function(data)  
        {  
            $scope.markers = [];  
            $scope.markers.push  
            ({  
                id: data.data.locationID,  
                coords:  
                {  
                    latitude: data.data.lat,  
                    longitude: data.data.long  
                },  
                title: data.data.title, //title of the makers  
                address: data.data.address, //Address of the makers  
                image: data.data.imagePath //image --optional  
            });  
            //set map focus to center  
            $scope.map.center.latitude = data.data.lat;  
            $scope.map.center.longitude = data.data.long;  
        }, function()  
        {  
            alert('Error'); //shows error if connection lost or error occurs  
        });  
    }  
    //Show or Hide marker on map using options passes here  
    $scope.windowOptions =  
    {  
        show: true  
    };  
}) 
//mapsController Ends Here
```

And also at your index.cshtml:

```
<li class="text-success" ng-repeat="l in locations" ng-click="ShowLocation(l.locationID)"><a href="#">{{l.title}}</a></li>
```